# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data' the parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I keep getting this exception when I start my program.

`System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'. The parameter is incorrect.`

Somewhere I read it could be caused by a corrupted package: I have tried to reinstall the NuGet package, but it's still not working.

NOTE: I'm not using Visual Studio, I'm coding a .NET Core class library using Jetbrains Riders on a Linux computer.

Comment: The proj file isn't matching what is installed on PC.  I usually create a new project and just add a some code using MySQL. Then open with notepad the new and old proj and compare the versions.

Comment: The csproj matches with the package version. I have tried to remove MySql.Data and use the package MySqlConnector, but I get the same error (it says MySqlConnector instead MySql.Data now...)

Comment: Use Solution Explorer and see if the library is in the reference section.

Comment: What version of the .NET Core runtime and SDK are you using? There are no known problems with loading MySqlConnector using .NET Core 2.1 on Linux: https://travis-ci.org/mysql-net/MySqlConnector

Comment: @GiantQuartz Nope, `dotnet add package MySqlConnector` should be all you need to start developing with MySqlConnector on .NET Core. I would need more concrete information on how to reproduce the failure to provide more help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an older version of MySql. Use the NuGet-Manager and download version 6.8.8 of MySql.Data, always worked for me.